# How to delete from nested STL containers

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

This is for homework. I have the program functioning properly, but I'm having trouble getting rid of the memory leaks.

I have a Class object.

I have a Class objectPtr, which has a pointer to an object Class.

I have...

```
typedef set<objectPtr> ObjectSet;
```

My objects are stored like this:

```
map<string, ObjectSet*>    myMap;
```

When I try to walk through the data structure, deleting objects (that's what I think I'm doing...) I cause my code to crash.

```
for(map<string, ObjectSet*>::const_iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
    for(ObjectSet::const_iterator e = it->second->begin(); e != it->second->end(); ++e)  
        delete e->getPtr();
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What is `ItemSet`? And what does `getPtr` return? How is `*e` defined? The code is not enough for us to help you.

Comment: Posted code looks fine, problem is somewhere else. Probably a mistake to store pointers in an STL container in the first place. It defeats many of the advantages of using the STL.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are storing raw pointers in standard containers? This is generally not a good idea due to the memory management and ownership issues that you are already experiencing. At the very minimum I would consider storing std::shared_ptrs  or std::unique_ptrs in the container if you *need* polymorphic behaviour or the actual values if you don't.

Comment: Is `class objectPtr` properly following the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))? Somehow, I'm leaning toward "no" on that.

Comment: OK, I made a correction- ItemSet changed to ObjectSet. getPtr() is just a function that returns the pointer to an "object" from "objectPtr." @Timo it's for a class, proff making us do it that way.

Comment: @WhozCraig- You're right I don't have a destructor for the objectPtr class, but I did try to implement one previously without success. I will however take another look at doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use basic RAII principles in the design of `objectPtr`. The general concept is to define a destructor for class `objectPtr` that calls delete on the stored pointer to `object`.  Then you just need one loop around the map to delete the raw pointer to `ObjectSet`.  Because `objectPtr` is stored as an instance (and not a pointer-to-instance), it's destructor will automatically be called when `ObjectSet` is destroyed.

Also, because you are calling delete in your for loop, you probably want non-const forward iterators.

Here's an example:

```
class object
{
   // ... interface details ...
};

class objectPtr
{
public:
   objectPtr(object* p) :
      ptr(p)
   {}

   ~objectPtr()
   {
      if (ptr)
         delete ptr;
   }

public:
   // ... interface details ...

private:
   object* ptr;
};


typedef set<objectPtr> ObjectSet;

map< string, ObjectSet* > myMap;

for(map< string, ObjectSet* >::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
{
   ObjectSet* setPtr = it->second;
   if (setPtr)
      delete setPtr; // ObjectSet will call 'delete' for each instance of 
                     // objectPtr, which through RAII, will automatically
                     // delete the referenced instance of object
}
```